# installing pygame through pip

Tags: python, windows, pygame, pip

I've been trying to install pygame, but I can't get it to work properly. I've tried installing the `.exe` file but when I tried to use it I got `ImportError: No module named 'pygame'`.

Then I tried using pip to install it and ended up using `pip install pygame==1.9.1 release --allow-external pygame --allow-unverified`

That downloaded the module but I got a bunch errors during installation.

a sample is `WARNING, DLL for vorbisfile library not found.`

I got many of those. Help?

Comment: pygame is based on libsdl and some more might needed on Windows. Good starting point is to get these DLL installed in you system -- These will not come with pip.

Comment: Have you tried the installer for you python version from (http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml)?